# SQL Server and iis create a lot of connections

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, fluent-nhibernate, autofac

I have an ASP.net mvc application that uses Fluent Nhiberate, SQL Server, and  autofac. When my application is published, IIS creates a lot of connections to SQL Server that are not being closed.

[image: there is a lot of not closing connections]

My `SessionManager` class:

```
public class SessionPerRequestModule : IHttpModule
{
    private static readonly string NH_SESSION_ISOK_KEY = "NH_SESSION_ISOK";
    private static readonly string NH_SESSION_PREFFIX_KEY = "NH_SESSION";

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.EndRequest += CtxEndRequest;
        context.Error += CtxOnError;
    }

    private void CtxOnError(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        context.Items[NH_SESSION_ISOK_KEY] = false;
    }

    private void CtxEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

        foreach (string dbKey in DatabaseKeys.AllKeys)
        {
            ISession session = GetCurrentSession(dbKey, false);
            CloseSession(session);
            SetSession(dbKey, null);
        }
    }

    public static bool IsOnError
    {
        get { return Convert.ToBoolean(HttpContext.Current.Items[NH_SESSION_ISOK_KEY]); }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Items[NH_SESSION_ISOK_KEY] = value; }
    }

    private static ISession OpenSession(string dbKey)
    {
        try
        {
            var interceptor = new SetSystemPropertiesInterceptor(
                () => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IAuthenticationService>()
            );

            ISession session;
            session = NHibernateSessionHelper.GetFactory(dbKey).OpenSession(interceptor);
            if (session == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Call to factory.OpenSession('{0}') returned null.", dbKey));

            session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Never;
            session.BeginTransaction();

            interceptor.SetSession(session);

            return session;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Error on database with key '{0}'", dbKey), ex);
        }
    }

    private static void CloseSession(ISession session)
    {
        if (session != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!IsOnError)
                {
                    if (session.Transaction != null && session.Transaction.IsActive)
                        session.Transaction.Commit();
                    else
                        session.Flush();
                }
                else
                    session.Transaction.Rollback();
            }
            finally
            {
                session.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    public static ISession GetCurrentSession(string dbKey)
    {
        return GetCurrentSession(dbKey, true);
    }

    public static ISession GetCurrentSession(string dbKey, bool createIfNotFound)
    {
        string fullKey = FormatFullContextKey(dbKey);
        ISession session = HttpContext.Current.Items[fullKey] as ISession;
        if (createIfNotFound && session == null)
        {
            session = OpenSession(dbKey);
            SetSession(dbKey, session);
        }
        return session;
    }

    private static void SetSession(string dbKey, ISession session)
    {
        string fullKey = FormatFullContextKey(dbKey);
        HttpContext.Current.Items[fullKey] = session;
    }

    private static string FormatFullContextKey(string dbKey)
    {
        return string.Concat(NH_SESSION_PREFFIX_KEY, "_", dbKey);
    }
}
```

Part of my NHibernate session helper:

```
factory = Fluently.Configure()
                  .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.FormatSql().ShowSql().AdoNetBatchSize(50).ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey(databaseKey)))
                  .Mappings(x =>
                       x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ColaboradorMapping>()
                       .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<CustomTypeConvention>()
                       ).BuildSessionFactory();
                            factories.Add(databaseKey, factory);
```

My Autofac injection:

```
public static IContainer RegisterAllDependencies()
{
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.Register(x => new VejoSeriesDb(SessionPerRequestModule.GetCurrentSession(DatabaseKeys.VejoSeriesDb))).As<IVejoSeriesDb>();
        builder.Register(x => new StarkDb(SessionPerRequestModule.GetCurrentSession(DatabaseKeys.MySQLStarkDb))).As<IStarkDb>();

        //session mongo
        builder.Register(x => new StarkMongoDb()).As<IStarkMongoDb>();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IUsuarioSerieN).Assembly)
        .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

        builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

        return container;
    }
```

Where I´m forgetting to close the connections?

Comment: .NET uses connection pooling. It's quite natural to see sleeping connections.

Comment: but my web sites not workink after a time...

Comment: this is crashing my website

Comment: did you try registering your db object as singleton..http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#single-instance